# Output voltage of an amplifier circuit

Tags: current, amplifier, load

I found this note on a devicesheet:
[image: High side current amplifier]

I'm asking about the output current:
How can we fin Iload = Vout/(RS*R2/R1) ?

For our example, we will take Vcc = 3V, we call Va the node crossing R1 and RS wires. We consider that the Op Amp is ideal.

Then IRS = ILoad

IRS = (Va-V-)/RS

Iload = (Va-V-)/RS (*)

Vout = R2/(R1+R2) (consider Vce = 0V)

And Vout = V+

IR1 = (Va - Vout)/R1

We use (*)
Iload = (IR1*R1 + Vout-V-)/RS

I'm a little lost. Can someone help me please?

Comment: One caution: My first thought on seeing that schematic was; that must be a very special op-amp. Its input voltage can be close to 44V with only a 3V supply. So, I looked up its datasheet (would be useful to link it in the question and ... it's a very special opamp, which works, even with inputs above its supply rail. So the caution is; this circuit will ONLY work with this opamp. (Or similar ones, if there are any).

Answer (score 2):

This diagram explains everything:

[image]

Thanks to the op-amp "action" we have \$ V_+ = V \scriptstyle -\$

And the voltage at output (voltage drop across\$ R_2\$) is equal to

$$ V_{out} = I_L \cdot R_S \cdot \frac{R_2}{R_1} \cdot \frac{ β + 1}{\beta} \approx  I_L R_S \cdot \frac{R_2}{R_1} $$

And here you have the alternative version with a PNP transistor.

[image]

$$ V_{out} = I_L \cdot R_S \cdot \frac{R_B}{R_A} \cdot \frac{β}{\beta + 1} \approx  I_L R_S \cdot \frac{R_B}{R_A} $$

And in this circuit (with PNP) the op-amp is supplied from the same voltage as the main circuit. And the opamp \$V_{oh}\$ (positive saturation voltage) is large then 0.6V. So, we are forced to add a Zener diode in series with the transistor base to lower the op-amp output voltage.

Comment: Does the alternative not use a PNP?

Comment: @DiBosco Good catch. Yep, PNP. I made a stupid typo.

Comment: How do you find:
Vout=IL⋅RS⋅R2R1⋅β+1β≈ILRS⋅R2R1?
What should we consider with a PNP compare to NPN?

Comment: @Tack which part of this equation you do not understand?

Comment: I don't understand the
[tex]RS.\frac{RB}{RA}[\tex]
How you found it?

Comment: And how do we add TeX equations?

Comment: Every voltage present at the \$V_+\$ input will appear at the T1 emitter. Hence \$I_E = \frac{V_+}{R_E}\$ The output voltage is \$ I_C *R_C\$ additional we know that \$I_E≈I_C\$ we have \$V_O =  \frac{V_+}{R_E} * R_C = V_+ *\frac{R_C}{R_E}\$

Comment: As for TeX used "\$" or "$$"

Comment: I'm making some calculus, but I always found:
\$I_E = \frac{V_{cc}-V^{+}}{R_E}\$.
Thats' work for TeX, thanks

Comment: But notice that \$V_{CC} - V+= I_L*R_s\$

Comment: Yes, you're right:
\$ \frac{V_{cc}-V^-}{R_s}}= \frac{V_{cc}-V^+}{R_s}} = \$
And we have the same current in the wire (consider input as infinite). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whatever volt-drop is across Rs gets balanced by the volt-drop across R1 due to Q1 being controlled by the op-amp. This is negative feedback in action - the op-amp seeks to make those voltages near-identical AND, this is the premise you start with. Although it might look like positive feedback, remember that Q1 collector inverts the voltage on its base.

So, the volt drop across Rs is exactly the same as the volt drop across R1.

So if the power supply is (say) 10 volts, and is supplying 1 amp through Rs, and Rs is 0.1 ohms, then the voltage on the load is 9.9 volts and, of course, the voltage at the inverting input is also 9.9 volts due to negative feedback.

This means that R1 also has 0.1 volts across it therefore, it must be passing a current of 0.5 mA R1 = 200 ohms). That current (ignoring base current that is assumed to be small) is also passing through R2 and thus generating an output voltage of 1 volt.

Does this help you?

Comment: There is something I didn't get from what you said. In the schematic, there is a positive feedback (on non inverting input connected to the output). How do you say 1 amp?

Comment: @Tack - the transistor is acting as an inverter hence it is negative feedback.

Comment: Yes, I missed that the output is negative because we're on collector output, and the input is on the base.
And I didn't get "Whatever volt-drop is across Rs gets balanced by the volt-drop across R1 due to Q1 being controlled by the op-amp"
When there is a current on the base, the transistor is on, and add a negative voltage to the non inverting input, but how could the volt drop across Rs is exactly the same as the volt drop across R1

Comment: Negative feedback magic, the opamp output tries to do whatever is necessary to make the voltage difference between the two inputs to zero V+=V-

Comment: @Tack the op-amp has an open loop DC gain of possibly 100k to 1M hence, for a sensible output voltage between its power rails, the inputs must be closer than a hair's breadth. Neg feedback ensures this - it is a classical control system.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it. Making a negative feedback in the non inverting input makes  me some trouble.
That's working as the usual Op-amp (positive feed-back on non inverting input).
On the case of the negative feedback on the positive input, do we have V+=V-?

Comment: @Tack but this circuit have negative feedback.The Q1 collector provides additional 180 degrees phase shift.  And this is why the Q1 collector is connected to the non-inverting input. https://i.stack.imgur.com/59bvB.png

Answer (score 0):

Let me continue your approach from the line *Vout=V+* in the following manner:

KCL at Vout: \$ \frac{V_{out}}{R_2}+\frac{V_{out}-V_{cc}}{R_1}=0\$

Therefore,                                                                                         $$V_{cc}=\frac{R_1+R_2}{R_2}.V_{out}$$
Now since \$I_L=\frac{V{cc}-V+}{R_s}\$, and \$V_+=V_{out}\$ we can write \$I_L\$ as a function of \$V_{out}\$ as the following:

$$I_L=\frac{V_{out}}{R_s(R_2/R_1)}$$

which is what the datasheet has reported. I assumed the transistor is in saturation and the collector-emitter voltage is 0V.

Comment: That assumption doesn't hold, especially with input voltages greater than the opamp supply.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you deserve a "+". 
But I'm asking how you find Il = (Vcc-V+)/Rs
I'll agree if we consider V+ = V-. How do you find it?